# How to handle error in threading when doing multiple schedule functions in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Hi I have multiple functions running with thread. I am wondering how do you handle error in running multiple threads where it does not affect the other threads that are running. When a function breaks, the other functions stops too. Do I use a try except for every schedule? Or is there a better way?

Current structure is like this.

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------run_threaded function

def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------scheduler function

#scheduler
print('scheduler is starting')
schedule.every().day.at('06:30').do(run_threaded,lambda:functionA())
schedule.every().day.at('06:30').do(run_threaded,lambda:functionB())
schedule.every().day.at('06:30').do(run_threaded,lambda:functionC())
schedule.every().day.at('06:30').do(run_threaded,lambda:functionD())
schedule.every().day.at('06:30').do(run_threaded,lambda:fucntionE())
schedule.every().day.at('22:00').do(lambda:email())
schedule.every().day.at('22:15').do(lambda:writeFile())

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: This question seems to have an answer in the schedule docs: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/exception-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to start by stating that [[Python.Docs]: threading - Thread-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading) does not actually do multithreading (on multiple *CPU*s), but it's more like a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*), **because of *GIL***. 
If you really want parallel execution, use [[Python.Docs]: multiprocessing - Process-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing).

But even if the above wasn't true, you actually do ***not*** have multithreading in your code. According to [[ReadTheDocs.Schedule]: Schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#schedule) (if this is the module you are using), the methods (like *do*) expect a function as a parameter (same as *threading.Thread* initializer), but **you're passing a function call** (the parentheses *()* at the end). 
So, you have **sequential** runs of the functions you're passing, and when the 1<sup>st</sup> one raises an exception, the whole program stops.

Taking the below line as an example:

```py
schedule.every().day.at('06:30').do(run_threaded, lambda: functionA())
```

1. In [[ReadTheDocs.Schedule]: Parallel execution](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parallel-execution.html#parallel-execution) (which was probably one of the sources of inspiration) **the (target) function isn't called**, so the above line should be:

   ```py
   schedule.every().day.at('06:30').do(run_threaded, lambda: functionA)  # functionA isn't called (no parentheses at the end) but it's rather passed as an argument
   ```
2. Not sure what's *lambda* purpose, things would look much simpler without it:

   ```py
   schedule.every().day.at('06:30').do(run_threaded, functionA)
   ```

Apply the above steps to all the calls, and I think you'd be fine (functions runs that raise exceptions won't affect the ones that don't - at least that's the behavior in *threading*), **in spite** of the following (in the *Schedule* documentation *URL*):

> When **not** to use Schedule
>
> ...
>
> - Concurrent execution (multiple threads)